# Progress Bar on Android gets displayed after complete onClick() execution

Tags: android, android-widget, android-button

I have a Button, and upon pressing it, the onClick() would process user's request.  However, this takes a little time, so I would like to have a View showing "Please wait, processing..." immediately upon pressing this Button, while its OnClickListener does its thing.

My problem is, this "Please wait, processing..." which I placed at the very beginning of onClick(), only appears AFTER the whole onClick() is done.  In other words, after the whole processing is done.  So, I was wondering, how do I make a View saying "Please wait, processing..." before the actual processing has begun?

Comment: Such time intensive tasks should usually be made with an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Long operations in an onClick are a no-no. This should also solve your problem of not showing the dialog, because the Task runs in background (like a Thread)

Answer (score 1):

As @Blundell pointed you may process long-running operation on a separate thread to avoid freezing of UI thread. However in Android there's a better alternative for general-purpose `Handler` which is called [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Please refer to [this](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-developmentthreading-part-2-async-tasks/) tutorial for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just using AsyncTask without dealing anything else.

- First create new AsyncTask class on "onPreExecute" change ui to show
  that you are processing sth
- Second do your all backend time consuming job on "doInBackground"
  method (do not call any ui updating method from here)
- Third change your ui to show that process is finished or whatever you
  wanna do.

  ```
  yourUiButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
      new NewTask().execute();
  }
  ```

  });

  ```
  class NewTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Task>{

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
                  //this part runs on ui thread
                  //show your "wait while processing" view
  }

  @Override
  protected Task doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                  //do your processing job here
                  //this part is not running on ui thread
      return task;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Task result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
                  //this part runs on ui thread
                  //run after your long process finished
                  //do whatever you want here like updating ui components
  }}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Do the processing on another thread so that the UI can show your dialog.

```
// Show dialog

// Start a new thread , either like this or with an ASyncTask
new Thread(){
     public void run(){
        // Do your thang

         // inform the UI thread you've finished
         handler.sendEmptyMessage();
     }
}
```

When the processing is done you will need to callback to the UI thread to dismiss oyur dialog.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
     public void handleMessage(int what){
          // dismiss your dialog
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks.

- Place the displaying of the progress dialog in onPreExecute
- Do your thing in doInBackground
- Update whatever needs to be updated in the UI, and close the dialog in onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this

```
public void onClick(View v){
  //show message "Please wait, processing..."
  Thread temp = new Thread(){

    @Override        
    public void run(){
      //Do everything you need
    }

  };
  temp.start();
}
```

or if you want it to run in the UIThread (since it is an intensive task, I don't recommend this)

```
public void onClick(View v){
  //show message "Please wait, processing..."
  Runnable action = new Runnable(){

    @Override        
    public void run(){
      //Do everything you need
    }

  };
  v.post(action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put ur code inside a thread and use a progress dialogue there...

```
void fn_longprocess() {
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, " Please wait", "..", true);
    fn_thread = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {

                // do your long process here

                runOnUiThread(UI_Thread);//call your ui thread here


            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
        } 

    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(null, thread1
    "thread1");
    thread.start();

}


  then close your dialogue in the UI thread...hope it helps..
```